# Split maxvalue partition in Oracle with new subpartition template

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, database-partitioning

How can I split maxvalue partition in Oracle with new subpartition template.

Or

How can I split maxvalue partition in Oracle and add also add new subpartitions parallely

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SPLIT PARTITION` as following:

**Oracle setup:**

> ```
> SQL> CREATE TABLE PART_EXAMPLE (
>   2      ID             NUMBER,
>   3      CREATED_DATE   DATE
>   4  )
>   5      PARTITION BY RANGE (
>   6          CREATED_DATE
>   7      )
>   8      ( PARTITION T1_2019
>   9          VALUES LESS THAN ( MAXVALUE )
>  10      );
>
> Table created.
> ```

**Checking the partitions:**

> ```
> SQL> SELECT
>   2      TABLE_NAME,
>   3      PARTITION_NAME
>   4  FROM
>   5      USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
>   6  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'PART_EXAMPLE';
>
> TABLE_NAME      PARTITION_
> --------------- ----------
> PART_EXAMPLE    T1_2019
> ```

**Splitting the partition into two partitions:**

> ```
> SQL> ALTER TABLE PART_EXAMPLE
>   2    SPLIT PARTITION T1_2019 AT (TO_DATE('31-DEC-2017 23:59:59', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
>   3    INTO (PARTITION T1_2017, PARTITION T1_2019)
>   4    ONLINE;
>
> Table altered.
> ```

**Now, Checking the partitions:**

> ```
> SQL> SELECT
>   2      TABLE_NAME,
>   3      PARTITION_NAME
>   4  FROM
>   5      USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
>   6  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'PART_EXAMPLE';
>
> TABLE_NAME      PARTITION_
> --------------- ----------
> PART_EXAMPLE    T1_2017
> PART_EXAMPLE    T1_2019
>
> SQL>
> ```

I hope it is clear.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the subpartitions template for a table. But this only affects new partitions. It has no impact on existing partitions:

```
create table t (
  c1 int, c2 int
) partition by range ( c1 ) 
  subpartition by hash ( c2 )
  subpartition template 2 
  (
    partition p0 values less than ( 1 ),
    partition pmax values less than ( maxvalue )
  );

select partition_name, subpartition_name
from   user_tab_subpartitions
where  table_name = 'T';

PARTITION_NAME    SUBPARTITION_NAME   
P0                SYS_SUBP2922         
P0                SYS_SUBP2923         
PMAX              SYS_SUBP2924         
PMAX              SYS_SUBP2925   

alter table t 
  set subpartition template 1;

select partition_name, subpartition_name
from   user_tab_subpartitions
where  table_name = 'T';

PARTITION_NAME    SUBPARTITION_NAME   
P0                SYS_SUBP2922         
P0                SYS_SUBP2923         
PMAX              SYS_SUBP2924         
PMAX              SYS_SUBP2925
```

You can also set the template while splitting. But again, this doesn't affect the existing partitions:

```
alter table t 
  split partition pmax at ( 2 )
  into ( 
    partition p1 set subpartition template 1, 
    partition pmax set subpartition template 1
  );

select partition_name, subpartition_name
from   user_tab_subpartitions
where  table_name = 'T';

PARTITION_NAME    SUBPARTITION_NAME   
P0                SYS_SUBP2922         
P0                SYS_SUBP2923         
P1                SYS_SUBP2926         
P1                SYS_SUBP2927         
PMAX              SYS_SUBP2924         
PMAX              SYS_SUBP2925
```

If you want to change the subpartitions while splitting a partition, define them in the subpartitions clause:

```
alter table t 
  split partition pmax at ( 3 )
  into ( 
    partition p2 subpartitions 1, 
    partition pmax subpartitions 4
  );

select partition_name, subpartition_name
from   user_tab_subpartitions
where  table_name = 'T';

PARTITION_NAME    SUBPARTITION_NAME   
P0                SYS_SUBP2936         
P0                SYS_SUBP2937         
P1                SYS_SUBP2940         
P1                SYS_SUBP2941         
P2                SYS_SUBP2942         
PMAX              SYS_SUBP2943         
PMAX              SYS_SUBP2944         
PMAX              SYS_SUBP2945         
PMAX              SYS_SUBP2946
```